# Is there a cleaner way adapt a standard observer/listener service using RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I've been tinkering with wrapping an old style listener interface using RxJava.  What i've come up with seems to work, but the usage of Observable.using feels a bit awkward.

The requirements are:

1. Only one subscription per id to the underlying service.
2. The latest value for a given id should be cached and served to new subscribers.
3. We must unsubscribe from the underlying service if nothing is listening to an id.

Is there a better way?  The following is what I've got.

```
static class MockServiceRXAdapterImpl1 implements MockServiceRXAdapter {
    PublishSubject<MockResponse> mockResponseObservable = PublishSubject.create();
    MockService mockService = new MockService(mockResponse -> mockResponseObservable.onNext(mockResponse));
    final ConcurrentMap<String, Observable<String>> subscriptionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public Observable<String> getObservable(String id) {
        return Observable.using(() -> subscriptionMap.computeIfAbsent(
                id,
                key -> mockResponseObservable.filter(mockResponse -> mockResponse.id.equals(id))
                        .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mockService.subscribe(id))
                        .doOnDispose(() -> {
                            mockService.unsubscribe(id);
                            subscriptionMap.remove(id);
                        })
                        .map(mockResponse -> mockResponse.value)
                        .replay(1)
                        .refCount()),
                observable -> observable,
                observable -> {
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think one problem with using `.filter(...)` here is that you'll have to invoke `id.equals(...)` for each response you receive from the service for each `id` you're currently subscribed to. This might not be an issue if you only have a few `ids`, but if you're subscribed to a 1000 `ids`, you'll be calling `id.equals(...)` 1000 times for each response you receive. Maybe it would be better to just maintain a `Map` of `id` to `PublishSubject`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Observable.create`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#create-io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe-)

So code may look like this

```
final Map<String, Observable<String>> subscriptionMap = new HashMap<>();
MockService mockService = new MockService();

public Observable<String> getObservable(String id) {
    log.info("looking for root observable");
    if (subscriptionMap.containsKey(id)) {
        log.info("found root observable");
        return subscriptionMap.get(id);
    } else {
        synchronized (subscriptionMap) {
            if (!subscriptionMap.containsKey(id)) {
                log.info("creating new root observable");
                final Observable<String> responseObservable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
                    MockServiceListener listener = emitter::onNext;
                    mockService.addListener(listener);
                    emitter.setCancellable(() -> {
                        mockServices.removeListener(listener);
                        mockService.unsubscribe(id);
                        synchronized (subscriptionMap) {
                            subscriptionMap.remove(id);
                        }
                    });
                    mockService.subscribe(id);
                })
                        .filter(mockResponse -> mockResponse.id.equals(id))
                        .map(mockResponse -> mockResponse.value)
                        .replay(1)
                        .refCount();

                subscriptionMap.put(id, responseObservable);
            } else {
                log.info("Another thread created the observable for us");
            }
            return subscriptionMap.get(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Your code doesn't account for having subscriptions to different ids at the same time, but it gives me a strategy to work with.  Will play.

Comment: It almost works, but it resubscribes to the mock service if :

 1. Get observer for 'A' (A1)
 2. subscribe to A1
 3. dispose subscription to A1
 4. Get another observer for 'A' (A2)
 5. Subscribe to A1
 6. Subscribe to A2.

Maybe avoiding this sort of issue is what the using keyword is for.

Comment: You have `refCount` call which means that original observable will be disposed when last observer unsubscribes

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/observables/ConnectableObservable.html#refCount--

Answer (score 0):

I think I've gotten it to work using `.groupBy(...)`.

In my case `Response.getValue()` returns an `int`, but you get the idea:

```
class Adapter
{
    Subject<Response> msgSubject;
    ThirdPartyService service;
    Map<String, Observable<Integer>> observables;
    Observable<GroupedObservable<String, Response>> groupedObservables;

    public Adapter()
    {
        msgSubject = PublishSubject.<Response>create().toSerialized();
        service = new MockThirdPartyService( msgSubject::onNext );
        groupedObservables = msgSubject.groupBy( Response::getId );
        observables = Collections.synchronizedMap( new HashMap<>() );
    }

    public Observable<Integer> getObservable( String id )
    {
        return observables.computeIfAbsent( id, this::doCreateObservable );
    }

    private Observable<Integer> doCreateObservable( String id )
    {
        service.subscribe( id );

        return groupedObservables
                .filter( group -> group.getKey().equals( id ))
                .doOnDispose( () -> {
                    synchronized ( observables )
                    {
                        service.unsubscribe( id );
                        observables.remove( id );
                    }
                } )
                .concatMap( Functions.identity() )
                .map( Response::getValue )
                .replay( 1 )
                .refCount();
    }
}
```